# use RegEx to ignore lines that contain a specific phrase but do not end with an extension and period

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Struggling to write a RegEx to use with my ANT FilterChain.

I am cleaning up a log file that contains entries such as (BAD ENTRY):

```
017Z WARN Broken: D:/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/../Images/Filename (stuff about file).
```

The log also contains entries like this (GOOD ENTRIES):

```
017Z WARN Broken: D:/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/../Images/Filename (stuff about file).ai.
```

I am able to successfully delete the "bad" entry and keep the "good" ones if I do something like this:

```
"^(?=.*WARN Broken:)(?!.*[.]ai.).*"
```

That, however, would force me to write a regex for all possible extensions.  I **actually don't know how to properly do the OR regex**, in this case, to even do that. I would like to be able to do **jpg, gif, eps, pdf in addition to ai**.

Ideally, I would like to be able to keep everything that ends with ".extension."
That last period really makes things complicated for me.

Comment: [`^(?!\w* WARN Broken:.*\.[^\/\r\n]+$).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/rMS5Gn/1)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would add the desired OR clause to your regex:

```
^(?=.*WARN Broken:)(?!.*[.](ai|jpg|gif|eps|pdf).).*
```

Comment: Apparently the simplicity of that failed me. Thanks.  Going with that approach.